# Kendo ui grid - checkbox,modal or radio button on specific cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

need help.

[Kendo ui Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8TXw.png)

Kendo grid code:

```
 $('#triggerParameterData').kendoGrid({
    columns: [{field: "name"},{field: "value"},{field: "description"}],

    selectable: "multiple,row",
    pageable: false,

    scrollable: false,
    editable: true,
    dataSource: {
        data: popup, schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    name: { editable: false },
                    description: { editable: false },

                }
            }
        }
    },
})
```

I want to make 2nd row value cell into a check box. if anyone have solution please share.
special thanks.

Comment: image attached in description "Kendo ui Grid".

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Kendo Grid Columns.Template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)

```
.....
columns: [

    {field: "name"},
    {field: "value", template: '<input type="checkbox" value="#: value #">'},
    {field: "description"}

]
......
```

Comment: thanks for response buddy but want checkbox only in one cell

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/Lsr5gmk7/#&togetherjs=wPQi23N29L)

**JS:**

```
var popup = [ { value:true, name: "Enos", description: "Es" },
                      { value:true,name: "Ray", description: "Rs" },
                      { value:true,name: "Justice", description: "Js" },
                      { value:true,name: "RR", description: "ESW" },
                      { value:true,name: "Gop", description: "Gp" },
                      { value:true,name: "DS", description: "JN" },
                      { value:true,name: "Raven", description: "Rv" },
                      { value:true,name: "FD", description: "FDGH" },
                      { value:true,name: "Andrew", description: "Ar" },
                      { value:true,name: "DDD", description: "GFG" },
                      { value:true,name: "Shayne", description: "S" },
                      { value:true,name: "YYY", description: "GHFGH" },
                      { value:true,name: "Walter", description: "W" },
                      { value:true,name: "EEE", description: "LUIO" },
                      { value:true,name: "ZKZG", description: "RD" },
                      { value:true,name: "JJJ", description: "FGJHGH" }];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#triggerParameterData').kendoGrid({
                columns: [{ field: "name" },
                          { field: "value", template: '<input type="checkbox" value="#: value #">' },
                          { field: "description" }],

                selectable: "multiple,row",
                pageable: false,

                scrollable: false,
                editable: true,
                dataSource: {
                    data: popup, schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                name: { editable: false },
                                value: { editable: false },
                                description: { editable: false },

                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            })

        });
```

Comment: thanks for response buddy but want checkbox only in one cell

Comment: You need to update the html in this case. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/Lsr5gmk7/2/#&togetherjs=wPQi23N29L)